# meaning of 'wasn't' in the example I posted , and was deleted for some unknown reason?

Tags: meaning

I posted this:

in an episode of Alfred Hichtcok presents, S03E38 , the nurse say:

"we wanted to call a doctor, but she said WE WASN'T TO." ( instead of we hadn'to)

it sound strange. Is this an old form or something?

thks

dan

you deleted it, why so?

What's wrong with that?  don't you know any possible answer?

Dan

Comment: Did the nurse speak with an accent different from others? All she did was switch *weren't* to *wasn't*, and the writers may have wanted to show a regional accent, perhaps Cockney.

Comment: Part of this question (i.e. "you deleted it, why so?) probably belongs on meta.

Comment: I think the writer's intention is the key. Some kind of accent being attempted. Nice Boris, there.

Comment: I see. Yes, it sound to me some kind of accent, non celtic thou' or maybe? So - we weren't to- take the place of -we hadn't to-  ? in any case here is the link  https://archive.org/details/Alfred_Hitchcock_Presents/Alfred+Hitchcock+Presents+(Complete)/Season+3+-+(1957-58)/S03E38+-+The+Impromptu+Murder.avi    the moment is at 11:58  !

Comment: Actually this is a wonderful way to learn English.